# Error in JD-GUI regarding variable names

Tags: java, decompiler, jd-gui

When looking at a jar file with JD-GUI I keep getting some sort of display error. It seems to replace variable names/identifiers with the symbol ��� (which in JD-GUI looks like a red snowman, picture attached). Any idea of how to fix this? I tried googling around but wasn't able to describe my situation very well and could therefore not find anyone with the same problem. Thanks in advance! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the identifier is unicode. You can fix that by using a decompiler like Procyon that escapes unicode. (You should be using Procyon anyway because JD-GUI is a poor decompiler).

Answer (score 0):

The class file should have be encrypted, you can see from the variable name and method name, I think the best way is finding an open source solution.

Comment: The code is obfuscated but that hasn't caused the appearance of the strange symbol in the past. What do you mean by encryption?

Comment: You can see from the assginments, this.i = xx.a(xx, xx), I think if somebody name a method using "a", and variables i,s,j,l, nobody can understand that code when reading it, this should have been encrypted at compile time, and the red snowman is just a variable reference name, just not using english.

Comment: I doubt that they used that symbol to identify a variable since it is used multiple times to refer to what should be different variables. The code was definitely obfuscated.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a snow man :). Posting rest of could would help but if you don't want to, use jad and maybe fern flower than compare the two. One should have the "right" naming

Comment: Okay, I'll try JAD and the fern to see if they work.